# Order of summation in MPI-reduce operations

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, mpi, hpc

We know that the different summation order of floating-point numbers could lead to the different results.

Consider the MPI function MPI_reduce called with the MPI_SUM operation.

```
#include <mpi.h>
int MPI_Reduce(const void *sendbuf, void *recvbuf, int count,
               MPI_Datatype datatype, MPI_Op op, int root,
               MPI_Comm comm)
```

Is it guaranteed by the MPI standard or MPI implementations that every time we run the function with the same input and output data, the results will be the same?

That's what I found in the [documentation](http://www.open-mpi.de/doc/v2.0/man3/MPI_Reduce.3.php)

> The ‘‘canonical’’ evaluation order of a reduction is determined by the
>   ranks of the processes in the group. However, the implementation can
>   take advantage of associativity, or associativity and commutativity,
>   in order to change the order of evaluation.

But this does not give any insight on the repeatability.

Comment: I would interpret "associativity and commutativity" as associativity and commutativity in a mathematical sense. Adding real numbers is both, but in reality adding floating point numbers is not associative nor commutative. Hence I would expect that the operations may be reordered, but you will get different results each time you run it

Comment: iirc, the standard at least strongly suggest to avoid non determinism in collectives. so as long as you use the same communicator, operations will be evaluated in the same order, and hence should produce identical results.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet that is what I would expect from the MPI library. I have a huge code base that delivers tiny deviations in results each time I run it. I wonder if I should look into MPI-exchange (or maybe in non-blocking operations) or it is something that comes from the serial part.

Comment: @paceholdernote this might not apply to non blocking collectives. what if you run your app with one MPI task ? do you still see deviations ? does a MPI task use thread parallelism (such as OpenMP or multithreaded libs such as MKL ?) btw, which MPI are you using ?

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet With one MPI-process it works just fine. This is a pure MPI code. I am not sure, it must be IBM implementation on this machine.

Comment: IBM Spectrum MPI is Open MPI based. You can try `mpirun --mca coll_basic_priority 100` and check if it helps. Does the code itself has some non deterministic behavior (such as performing floating operations as the message arrives in an undetermined manner) ?

Comment: I need to dig deeper in the code -- it is hard to say now what could go wrong...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [actual standard](http://mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-3.1/mpi31-report.pdf) gives some further insight:

> *Advice to implementors.*  It is strongly recommended that `MPI_REDUCE` be
>   implemented so that the same result be obtained whenever the
>   function is applied on the same arguments, appearing in the same
>   order. Note that this may prevent optimizations that take advantage
>   of the physical location of ranks. *(End of advice to implementors.)*

So, while there is no guarantee, I would expect that implementations follow this recommendation and do produce reproducible results.

Comment: thanks ! fwiw, Open MPI follows this recommendation.

Comment: For Intel MPI (as of version 2021.6), it seems you need to set [`I_MPI_CBWR=1`](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/mpi-developer-reference-linux/top/environment-variable-reference/i-mpi-adjust-family-environment-variables.html#i-mpi-adjust-family-environment-variables_GUID-A5119508-5588-4CF5-9979-8D60831D1411) to disable topology-aware collectives and get reproducible results.

Answer (score 3):

If you have the same number of ranks with an identical physical placement across nodes and cores each time you run then you would probably expect the same result each time (though, as you see above, the standard does not guarantee this).

In practice, on shared use HPC systems, you do not often achieve exactly the same placement so the reduction order usually differs and you see small differences due to the different order of reduction operations.

I should also say: even if you consistently replicate physical layout, operation order can still potentially differ due to different conditions on shared infrastructure (interconnect or disk, even nodes if their use is non-exclusive). If other users are loading the system in different ways it can change the ordering of data reaching each rank and thus the order of the operations (depending on the parallel reduction algorithm).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. In my case it is about running  the same code with the same initial values over and over again on the same machine. As far as I know, MPI is a topology aware library and it can optimize the reduction order to fit it to the network topology. But I guess it shouldn't be random on repeatable runs with the same initial conditions.